# Why distance between point and image of exponential map is travel time?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M, g)$ be a compact manifold with strictly convex boundary. The distance function $d_{g}: M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by
$$
d_{g}(x, y)=\inf _{\gamma \in \Lambda_{x, y}} \ell_{g}(\gamma)
$$
where $\Lambda_{x, y}$ denotes the set of smooth curves $\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$ and
$$
\ell_{g}(\gamma):=\int_{0}^{1}|\dot{\gamma}(t)|_{g} d t.
$$
Now we know that on a simple manifold, the exponential map
$$
\exp _{x}: D_{x} \rightarrow M
$$
is a diffeomorphism. So for any pair of points in $M$ there is a unique geodesic between them, and this geodesic minimizes length. Now if we consider $t v \in D_{x}$ and $|v|_{g}=1$, then I need to show following
$$
f\left(\exp _{x}(t v)\right)=d_{g}\left(x, \exp _{x}(t v)\right)=t.
$$

What I was thinking is following:

By definition:
\begin{align*}
d_{g}\left(x, \exp _{x}(t v)\right)&=\int_{0}^{1}|\dot{\exp_{x}}(tv)|_{g} d t\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}|v|_g|\dot\gamma_{x,v}(t)|_g dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}|\dot\gamma_{x,v}(t)|_g dt
\end{align*}

Now $\gamma$ is geodesic so it has unit length so $||\dot\gamma_{x,v}(t)|_g|=|\dot\gamma_{x,v}(0)|_g=|v|_g=1$.

But I need to show that  equals to $t$. where is I am making mistakes
Please help me.

Any help/hint/reference will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is a problem in your notations: either $t$ is a data in $\exp(tv)$, either it is a mute variable of integration, but it definitely cannot be both! I think the confusion comes from there.

Comment: I'm confused: Are you **assuming** that $D_x$ is such that $\exp_x: D_x\to M$ is a diffeomorphism? Also, what is $f$? Is this just the distance from $x$ to $\exp_x(tv)$? If so, the claim trivially holds.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks Sir for response. Yes it is domain for which exponential is diffeomorphism and f(y) is distance from x. How claim trivially true? I could not able to justify that. Can you please throw some light on that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your notations for the last integrals are messed up. Also, you used the facts that radial geodesics are locally minimizing and almost finished the computation, but you missed a couple things: first, the integral which appears in the distance equality can be taken from $0$ to $1$ only when the geodesic is *not* unit speed (so either you drop the assumption that $\|v \| = 1$ or you change the bounds of the integral - you can't do both), and also that geodesics have constant speed. So let us establish that $\gamma_v$ is given by $\gamma_v(u) = \exp_p(u v)$ where $0 \leq u \leq s$. Then

$$\mathrm{dist}(x, \exp_p(s v) ) =  \int_{0}^{s} \| \gamma'_{v}(t) \| \ \mathrm{d} t  =  \int_{0}^{s} \| \gamma'_{v}(0) \| \ \mathrm{d} t = \int_{0}^{s} \| v\| \ \mathrm{d} t = s \cdot \|v\| $$

Notice also that this is only true in the same local sense that geodesics are locally minimizing (i.e, it is only true for small enough $s$) - we crucially used the locally minimizing property of geodesics in the first equality. If $\|v\|$ is of unit length you get the result your desire. Of course, if you really wanted to parameterize the geodesic from $0$ to $1$, you could just define $\alpha: [0, 1] \to M$ by $\alpha_v(t) = \gamma(s \cdot t)$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Then we would again get:

$$\mathrm{dist}(x, \exp_p(s v) ) =  \int_{0}^{1} \| \alpha'_{v}(t) \| \ \mathrm{d} t  =  \int_{0}^{1} \| \alpha'_{v}(0) \| \ \mathrm{d} t = \int_{0}^{1} s \cdot \| v\| \ \mathrm{d} t = s \cdot \|v\| $$